# Angular:How to do progress bar checklist

Tags: angular, angular8

I want to do progress bar checklist like a **Trello** but I don't how to do this I don't know how begin.
example in Trello
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrqNQ.png)

*HTML*

```
<div *ngFor="let task of depositTasks; let i = index">
                            <div>
                              <div *ngIf="taskIdx!==i">
                                <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="task.checked(change)="changeChecked()"
                                  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                                {{task?.subjectTask}}
                                {{getDev(task)}}
                                {{task?.point}}
                                {{task?.dueDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
                                {{task?.checked}}
                             </div>
                          </div>
</div>
```

*ts*

```
  progressbar() {
   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

Ts

```
progress: Object;

progressbar() {
    const total = this.depositTasks.length;
    const completed = this.depositTasks.
        .reduce((done, task) => done += Number(task.checked), 0);
    this.progress = {width: (completed/total) + ’%’};
}
```

Html

```
<div style=“width: 500px; height:20px;background:white;border-radius:8px;”>
    <div [ngStyle]=“progress” style=“background:blue”></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can simple "count" the checked:`100*this.depositTasks.filter(x=>x.checked).length/this.deposit.Task.length`, even you can write in .html: `<div [style.width]="100*this.depositTasks.filter(x=>x.checked).length/this.deposit.Task.length+'%'” style=“background:blue"></div>`

Comment: Which line of your HTML should I put?

Comment: You can put it at the very tops of your snippet. above the enclosing div with the ngFor.